# Probability generating functions of coin tosses

Tags: probability, generating-functions

I have just came across a weird definition for the probability generating function of a random variable $N$ that denotes the integer value for the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ toss on which the coin turned out to be heads.

First of all, I always thought that the lower bound in the sum for the definition of probability generating function is zero, i.e.:

$$G(x) = \sum_{\color{red} {i=0}}^{\infty}x^i P(X=x_i)$$

I also thought the the toss on which heads is to turn up is independent of the previous tosses and as such at each toss, the probability is always constant ... i.e. a $1/2$. Now the definition of the pgf that I just saw is:

$$G(x) = \sum_{\color{red} {i=1}}^{\infty} x^i \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^i$$

This can be seen here: [STEP III,2011,Q12](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=1697768&p=32634784#post32634784) (post number $11$).

I would imagine that the pgf has to be:

$$G(x) = \sum_{\color{red} {i=0}}^{\infty} x^i \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Sorry...not following.  the probability that toss $k$ turns out to be the toss on which you get your $n^{th}$ $H$ is clearly not a constant.  Say $n=1$.  Then the probability that you get the first $H$ on the $k^{th}$ toss is $\frac 1{2^k}$.

Comment: the question is basically: find a pgf of random variable $N$. And $N$ is the integer value of the first time that you see a head when you flip the coin. So for example we flip the coin $4$ times and on the $4$th flip it is head. Then $N=4$. (and on the previous three flips it is tails).

Comment: Can't find the post. But it is clear that the random variable $N$ has value $n$ if the first head occurs on the $n$-th toss. The pgf is then $\sum_1^\infty (1/2)^n x^n$.

Comment: Ok, that's not how I read it but, as it happens, that's the example I used.  For the first $H$ to occur on the $k^{th}$ trial, you need $k-1$ $T's$ followed by an $H$...whence $\frac 1{2^k}$.

Comment: why do we start the pgf from $i=1$? and not a zero?

Comment: The probability that you get the first $H$ on the $0^{th}$ throw is $0$.

Comment: alright. all clear now. thanks